# set parameter value to 'not equal'

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report that shows some records. Some of these records have a blank field, so I am trying to set a parameter to switch between records with this field completed, and those with this particular field empty.

I am using a filter on the tablix to say if one field is equal to the parameter value than show those records.

So, I have setup a parameter and have 2 available values.

`Open` is `=""`

and now i want to set a value for `closed` which will return all records that don't have a blank `resolved` field.

When i run the report, the records come back as expected for `open` but i cannot work out how to say 'not equal to an empty string' to get the other records to return.

Can this be done?

Comment: I'm assuming you already tried Operator = `<>`, Value = `""`?

Comment: For `open` i am using `=""`. Have tried to use `<>` for not equal, but doesn't seem to like it

Comment: Could you try `Nothing` instead of `""` in the second filter?  You might need to go into Expression Builder to do this - click the little fx next to the value...

Comment: @Neal1581 please illustrate your comment.   How did you try `<>`, and what error did you get?   It should work if you do it correctly.

Comment: I have used `<>""` as `closed` value to say 'not equal to empty string' This does not create an expression though, and you just see the `<>""` in the value box. When report runs, `open` shows all records with the resolved field empty. When selecting `closed`, all records are visible.

Comment: You need to compare something with the empty string. Also don't forget to put an `=` sign to begin with and declare an expression... `=Fields!FieldName.Value <> ""`

Comment: What is the datatype of the column Resolved? what is the value when Open and what is the value when closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am confused.  If you have a parameter and values for it are, presumably: open and close.  In the SQL query against the SQL Server, you can put in your Where:

```
1 = case when @param = 'open' and isnull(resolved,'') = '' then 1 
         when @param = 'closed' and isnull(resolved,'') != '' then 1 else 0 end
```

Comment: Yes, it appears this is the best way to do it, was just seeing if there was a solution using a tablix filter and parameter values.